# C# regex: negative lookahead fails with the single line option

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to figure out why a regex with negative look ahead fails when the "single line" option is turned on.

Example (simplified):

```
<source>Test 1</source>
<source>Test 2</source>
<target>Result 2</target>
<source>Test 3</source>
```

This:

```
<source>(?!.*<source>)(.*?)</source>(?!\s*<target)
```

will fail if the single line option is on, and will work if the single line option is off. For instance, this works (disables the single line option):

```
(?-s:<source>(?!.*<source>)(.*?)</source>(?!\s*<target))
```

My understanding is that the single line mode simply allows the dot "." to match new lines, and I don't see why it would affect the expression above.

Can anyone explain what I am missing here?

::::::::::::::::::::::

EDIT: (?!.*) is a **negative look ahead** not a capturing group.

```
 <source>(?!.*?<source>)(.*?)</source>(?!\s*<target)
```

will ALSO FAIL if the single line mode is on, so it doesn't look like this is a greediness issue. Try it in a Regex designer (like Expresso or Rad regex):

With single line OFF, it matches (as expected):

```
<source>Test 1</source>    
<source>Test 3</source>
```

With single line ON:

```
<source>Test 3</source>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't match the first one as well: it does not contain the first negative look ahead, so it should match the expression.

Comment: Do yourself a favor by parsing this using an html parser instead of regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Waiting for a comment from John Saunders: 3...2...1...

Comment: @Amarghosh. Not relevant in my context. Yes, there are contexts where using regex IS the thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<source>((?:(?!</?source>).)*)</source>(?!\s*<target)
```

The idea is that you match each character one at a time, but only after making sure it isn't the first character of `</source>`.  Also, with the addition of `/?` to the lookahead, you don't have to use a non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: +1; I made a mistake in my suggested "fix" in the comment (now deleted). This one works.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot, Alan!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it "fails" is because you seem to have misplaced the negative lookahead.

```
<source>(?!.*<source>)(.*?)</source>(?!\s*<target)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, let's consider what `(?!.*<source>)` does here: it's a lookahead that says that there is *NO* match for `.*<source>` from that position.

Well, in single-line mode, `.` matches everything. After matching the first two `<source>`, there *IS* in fact `.*<source>`! So the negative lookahead fails for the first two `<source>`.

On the last `<source>`, `.*<source>` no longer match, so the negative lookahead succeeds. The rest of the pattern also succeeds, and that's why you only get `<source>Test 3</source>` in single-line mode.

Comment: Using negative character classes is simpler and quicker: `<source>([^<]*)</source>(?!\s*<target>)`

Comment: @pent: I can't use character classes in this case because the source tag can contain other tags (and square brackets) which also need to be matched.